# printf, how to insert decimal point for integer

Tags: c, printf

I have an `UINT16` unsigned integer of say

```
4455, 312, 560 or 70.
```

How to use printf to insert a decimal point before the last two digits so the example numbers appear as

```
44.55, 3.12, 5.60 or 0.70
```

If there is no printf solution, is there another solution for this?

I do not wish to use floating point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%.2d` could add the extra padding zeros

```
printf("%d.%.2d", n / 100, n % 100);
```

For example, if `n` is `560`, the output is: `5.60`

**EDIT** : I didn't notice it's `UINT16` at first, according to @Eric Postpischil's comment, it's better to use:

```
printf("%d.%.2d", (int) (x/100), (int) (x%100));
```

Comment: `d` may be the wrong format specifier. The XC16 compiler targets some embedded processors with small word sizes. It may be that the `UINT16` type of `x` is an `unsigned int`, and the `u` specifier should be used. Or it may be that `UINT16` is shorter than an `int` and is therefore promoted to an `int`, and the `d` specifier is correct. The easiest way to deal with this might be to cast the arguments, using `printf("%d.%.2d", (int) (x/100), (int) (x%100));`.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("%d.%.2d", x / 100, x % 100);
```

Comment: `d` may be the wrong format specifier. The XC16 compiler targets some embedded processors with small word sizes. It may be that the `UINT16` type of `x` is an `unsigned int`, and the `u` specifier should be used. Or it may be that `UINT16` is shorter than an `int` and is therefore promoted to an `int`, and the `d` specifier is correct. The easiest way to deal with this might be to cast the arguments, using `printf("%d.%.2d", (int) (x/100), (int) (x%100));`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **printf** directly **with out using float**

```
printf("%d.%02d", num/100, num%100);
```

%02d means right align with zero padding.

```
if num is 4455 ==>output is 44.55  
if num is 203  ==>output is 2.03
```

**EDIT:**
 by seeing comment from  @ Eric Postpischil , it's better to use like this.

```
printf("%d.%02d", (int) (num/100), (int) (num%100));
```

Answer (score 0):

with a int x1000 precision 1234123 -> 1234.123

```
printf("%4d.%.3d\n", x / 1000, x % 1000);
```

if you need to round to 2 decimal

```
printf("%4d.%.2d\n", ((x+5)/10) / 100, ((x+5)/10) % 100);
```

only tested with positive

```
input        print
000004       0.00
000005       0.01

000014       0.01
000015       0.02

000100       0.10
000101       0.10

000105       0.11
000994       0.99
000995       1.00
...
```

Comment: snprintf(sbuf,sizeof(sbuf),"Vcc = %2u.%.3u\n", (int)(x / 1000), (int)(x % 1000));
if you are using long